# test empty queue in c

Tags: c, testing, queue

I want to test a function called  `queue_empty()` and check if it actually creates an empty queue or not. Here's the code for the function that is testing the other function:

```
void create_empty_test()
{

// Creates empty list.  
queue *q=queue_empty(NULL);

    // Verify that list is empty.
    if (????) {
        //error message.
        fprintf(stderr, "FAIL. New queue is not empty!\n");
        // clean up .
        queue_kill(q);
        // Exit with error.
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Everything okay
    queue_kill(q);
}
```

What should I write where the questionmarks are? Sorry if this question is bad, I am really new to C, queues, lists and pointers etc. I'm thankful for all answers and explanations.

Comment: Depends on what `queue` is. You're not showing that.

Comment: What you have so far is `q = queue_empty(NULL)` which ostensibly gives you a valid pointer to an empty queue. Based upon the structure of `queue` you need to know what an empty one looks like. You haven't indicated the meaning of `queue` so nobody here can answer that for you. The ???? would be checking `q->something` for a NULL or something like that, but it's just an educated guess based upon what little information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

A good queue implementation should have emptiness check API, like `int is_empty(queue *)` or `void *queue_top(queue *)`. Use that API.

If API is yours, then implement those emptiness check APIs.